# Unable to call function within same GAS script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have two function, one reads the Cell value upon change.

And the second one makes a Request to a URL and gets the response.

```
 function onEdit(e) {
     var range = e.range;
     var data = range.getValue();
     Logger.log(data)
     Logger.log(test());
 }


 function test() {
     var url = 'apps.compete.com/sites/wholesalerhinestones.org/trended/UV/?apikey=[YOUR API KEY HERE]';

     var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
     Logger.log(response);
 }
```

Problem is that, `test()` runs successfully and Logs the output to Console but upon Cell change event, cell's value is logged but `test()` is not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the issues here is you're not actually calling the function, nor are you returning anything should it be called.

It should look something like this:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var range = e.range;
  var data = range.getValue();
  Logger.log(data)
  var testedFunction = test();
  Logger.log(testedFunction);
 }


function test(){
var url = 'YOUR-URL-HERE';
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
Logger.log('Response code: ' + response.getResponseCode());
return response 
}
```

The second issue that you're having here is that your using a [Simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/index?hl=fr-FR#restrictions) which *does not* allow you to access services which require authorization.

Instead using an [Installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable?hl=fr-FR#google_apps_triggers) for 'onEdit' might do the trick. (This is what I was using, but I was testing against 'Google.com'). It should look like this:
[image]

Comment: It does not work also ... :( Please run the code at your side for test

Comment: does not work for me :( Is it something related to permissions?

Comment: I've edited my code slightly, and added in a Log for response.getResponseCode(). If this does not equal 200, the problem is connecting to the URL that you're using. See if it works with a generic URL, such as google.com, and if it does, the issue doesn't lie with Apps script, but with your URL.

Comment: it does not even Log `Response code: `  .. looks like there might be Exception .. how can I put that in try-catch and see what is error .. as I said .. I can successfully call `test()` individually

Comment: What happens when you try a generically accessible URL such as 'google.com'?

Comment: Hey ... I put that code in try catch ... and I got this `Exception: You do not have permission to call fetch`  when onEdit() is called

Comment: Ah, thus we have light at the end of the tunnel. I'll update my answer now with the solution.

Comment: Yessss ... making a custom function and trigerring it upon onEdit() workds